# How Do I Structure MongoDB To Query By Date Time Per Minute?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I am trying to store the price of stocks price per minute, so I can easily return results based on the minute date time per minute interval and store historical data, so i can query like last 24 hours, last 30 days etc (please also let me know if this is wrong approach)

for example if i check current time with `fmt.Println("time now: ", time.Now())` i get the following date time `2022-01-29 11:47:02.398118591 +0000 UTC m=+499755.770119738`

so what i want is to only get up to minute level, so i can store per minute
so i will liek to use this date time `2022-01-29 11:47:00 +0000 UTC`
I will like to UTC, so i can stick to that universal time zone to store and retrive data

Each row will be a list of multiple stock price data
Do i need to have the `_id` field? Am not sure, so just looking for best practice as help.

`database name: "stock-price-db"`

`collection name: "stock-price"`

> Thinking of something like this, just for example

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5458b6ee09d76eb7326df3a4"),
        "2022-01-29 11:48:00 +0000 UTC":
            [
                {
                    "stock": "TSLA",
                    "price": "859.83",
                    "marketcap": "8938289305",

                }, 
                {
                    "stock": "AAPL",
                    "price": "175.50",
                    "marketcap": "3648289305",

                },  
            ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5458b6ee09d76eb7326df3a4"),
        "2022-01-29 11:47:00 +0000 UTC":
            [
                {
                    "stock": "TSLA",
                    "price": "855.50",
                    "marketcap": "8848289305",

                }, 
                {
                    "stock": "AAPL",
                    "price": "172.96",
                    "marketcap": "3638289305",

                }, 
            ]
    },
]
```

First, `is this the right way` to do store this type of data in mongodb and `how do I structure the model` to store the data this way so I can store the data per minute interval, so I can query per minute interval?

Comment: it is a purely database-related question and I don't know why you say in Golang in your question.

Comment: To trim a time instant down to a specific precision use [`time.Time.Truncate`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Truncate)

Comment: I'm not sure MongoDB is the right tool for such job: what you're after is actually a time-series data, and specialized solutions such as [ClickHouse](https://clickhouse.com/) should have your performance issues covered for a longer run of data you're going to _accumulate._

Comment: As to `_id`, you cannot forfeit using it because any collection in MongoDB must have at least a single unique index, and `_id` is one. I'd recommend to better compe up with what is unique about your records, and it appears to be the time instant. All-in-all, I'm with @Gibbs on the points they've presented in their respective answer (except that the [language is called Go, not Golang](https://go.dev/doc/faq#go_or_golang)).

Comment: wow..i was thinking mongodb would be the right tool for the job..thanks for sharing recommendations to go for more dedicated time series database... @kostix seems you recommend **clickhouse** over the others? i want to go with the best fit for the task...seems mongodb added time series feature https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/new-time-series-collections/...also what about **rethinkdb**?

Comment: I have no say about rethinkdb since I've no experience with it. We're extensively using CH at my $dayjob to keep time-series data—mostly compressed logs, but we had a go at it to store time-series data and I saw it with my own eyes that it handles a complex aggregation request against a 1 full year of data for some FXCM symbol in under 2 seconds. That was a PoC with a single instance, no sharding, no optimizations, no nothing.

Answer (score 2):

There are few drawbacks in your design.

1. Do not use dynamic keys - you will end up using few extra aggregation pipelines.
2. Store the date in a static-key field i.e time:ISODate()
3. Better store all the available time units, till milliseconds, it will be helpful to handle the future requirement changes
4. If there are too many stocks changes, it is not a scalable design.
5. If you want to find out historical data for a stock, provided design may have performance issues.
6. You will end up with issues in sharding.

What other alternatives:

1. Not all the use-cases can be solved by one design.
2. If this use case is purely for time series use case, I would recommend you to use a time series design/ time series database i.e influx, tsdb.
3. If you need to cover all the use-cases, normalise and use GQL.

Comment: regarding time series database, you think **influxdb** will be better than **clickhouse** or **rethinkdb**? also seems mongodb supports time series specifically now https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/new-time-series-collections/#how-to-create-a-time-series-collection

Comment: My experience with influx is super. I havent explored much on other time series databases.

Comment: what i know of influxdb is for monitoring...is it a good fit for like an app..to query data and have persistent and consistent data consumed by a golang app for example?

Comment: did you check this? https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/new-time-series-collections/ seems mongodb added support for time series...i might go with mongodb then with this...since i will be using it for other parts of apps that are not time sensitive

Comment: I would recommend you to evaluate the options for your data, schema. With mongo, you can achieve many things based on your schema. Mongo db documentation itself suggests to evaluate multiple schemas.

Comment: i think am sold with mogodb here => https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/new-time-series-collections/#granularity so i will stick with mongodb and research more on the time series documentation

Comment: All the best. Looking forward for your feedback.